# Flink HBase input for machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, hbase, apache-flink

I would like to use the Flink-HBase addon to read out data that then serves as an input for the Flink machine learning algorithms, respectively the SVM and MLR. Right now I first write the extracted data to a temporary file and then read it in via the libSVM method, but I guess there should be a more sophisticated way.

Do you have a code snippet or an idea how to do so?

Comment: Flink is relatively new project. I think, you might get better help on flink mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to write the data to disk and then read it with `MLUtils.readLibSVM`. The reason is the following.

`MLUtils.readLibSVM` expects a text file where each line is the sparse feature vector with its associated label. It uses the following format to represent the label-feature vector pair:

```
<line> .=. <label> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
```

Where `<feature>` is the index of the subsequent `value` in the feature vector. `MLUtils.readLibSVM` can read files with this format and converts each line in a `LabeledVector` instance. Thus, you obtain a `DataSet[LabeledVector]` after having read the a libSVM file. And this is exactly the input format you need for the `SVM` and `MultipleLinearRegression` predictor.

However, depending on the data format you obtain from HBase, you first have to convert the data into the `libSVM` format. Otherwise, `MLUtils.readLibSVM` won't be able to read the written file. And if you convert the data, then you can also directly convert your data to a `DataSet[LabeledVector]` and use it as the input for Flink's ML algorithms. This avoids an unnecessary disk cycle.

If you obtain from HBase a `DataSet[String]` where each string has the `libSVM` format (see the specification above), then you can apply a `map` operation on the HBase `DataSet` with the following map function.

```scala
val hbaseInput: DataSet[String] = ...
val labelCOODS = hbaseInput.flatMap {
  line =>
    // remove all comments which start with a '#'
    val commentFreeLine = line.takeWhile(_ != '#').trim

    if(commentFreeLine.nonEmpty) {
      val splits = commentFreeLine.split(' ')
      val label = splits.head.toDouble
      val sparseFeatures = splits.tail
      val coos = sparseFeatures.map {
        str =>
          val pair = str.split(':')
          require(
            pair.length == 2, 
            "Each feature entry has to have the form <feature>:<value>")

          // libSVM index is 1-based, but we expect it to be 0-based
          val index = pair(0).toInt - 1
          val value = pair(1).toDouble

          (index, value)
      }

      Some((label, coos))
    } else {
      None
    }

// Calculate maximum dimension of vectors
val dimensionDS = labelCOODS.map {
  labelCOO =>
    labelCOO._2.map( _._1 + 1 ).max
}.reduce(scala.math.max(_, _))

val labeledVectors: DataSet[LabeledVector] = 
  labelCOODS.map{ new RichMapFunction[(Double, Array[(Int, Double)]), LabeledVector] {
  var dimension = 0

  override def open(configuration: Configuration): Unit = {
    dimension = getRuntimeContext.getBroadcastVariable(DIMENSION).get(0)
  }

  override def map(value: (Double, Array[(Int, Double)])): LabeledVector = {
    new LabeledVector(value._1, SparseVector.fromCOO(dimension, value._2))
  }
}}.withBroadcastSet(dimensionDS, DIMENSION)
```

This will convert your libSVM format data into a data set of  `LabeledVectors`.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful! 
Unfortunately, the dataset from HBase has to be obtained within a Java class and now I get the error that my DataSet is incompatible for a method within a Scala-Class:

`Error:(102, 29) java: incompatible types: 'org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet<java.lang.String>'`

Comment: You should also be able to read from HBase using the Scala API. Then you obtain a `org.apache.flink.api.scala.Dataset[String]`.